The protocol requires sending a header with the WebSocket connection
I am trying to open a WebSocket with JavaScript to connect to an OCPP server. The specifications require sending an AUTHORIZATION header with the WebSocket connection. However, I see that this is not possible with WebSockets because they do not support custom headers. Does that make sense? why they ask something that can't be done?
ocpp 2.0.1 specs
The Charging Station should include the same header as used in Basic Auth RFC 2617, while
requesting to upgrade the http connection to a websocket connection as described in RFC 6455.
The server first needs to validate the Authorization header before upgrading the connection.
Example:
GET /ws HTTP/1.1
Remote-Addr: 127.0.0.1
UPGRADE: websocket
CONNECTION: Upgrade
HOST: 127.0.0.1:9999
ORIGIN: http://127.0.0.1:9999
SEC-WEBSOCKET-KEY: Pb4obWo2214EfaPQuazMjA==
SEC-WEBSOCKET-VERSION: 13
AUTHORIZATION: Basic <Base64 encoded(<ChargePointId>:<AuthorizationKey>)>


Unfortunately you only claim that it does not work. The linked question show otherwise though. If you still think that the problem exists please show the relevant code and context (browser, nodejs, ... ?) of what you've actually tried.

@Steffen The second linked dupe in which it works if about node.js. In the browser, it still simply doesn't work (first dupe).

You're probably not meant to be using this API from a browser?

but i want to create an app with js that use this api

Then you probably have to create your own server. That server connects via websocket to the OCPP server to receive data. You then manage your own websocket connections to your own users yourself. The OCPP server probably has no interest in needing to scale its infrastructure to handle your users directly.
